# Is it possible to run OpenCV on Raspberry Pi Pico onboard?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi, camera, raspberry-pi-pico

I need to build standalone module which records video from rasberry pi camera to sd card (through external module) when the motion on video is detected.

So, I need to run OpenCV that I will use for motion detection. Is it possible to run it on Raspberry Pi Pico on board? How much FPS will it have in case for i.e. background subtraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The RPi Pico uses an RP2040](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-pico/).

RP2040 is a dual-core ARM Cortex-M0+. It comes with "264kB on-chip SRAM". You shouldn't expect this to have any power that's useful for image processing. It doesn't even run Linux. Were those 264 kB fully available to you, you could fit *a single grayscale image of size 593x445* in there.

OpenCV can target ARM but not such tiny microcontrollers.

Here's some evaluations by OpenCV itself: https://opencv.org/arm/

You should investigate "OpenVX".

Comment: Can I add additional memory by soldering some chips or by using microsd module?

Comment: Will OpenVX work on Pi Pico?

Comment: microsd is storage, not RAM. you can "solder" additional RAM to most microcontrollers. I would however recommend going with a Cortex-A instead. they can run linux, and they're the right architecture for OpenCV... at least there's a chance it'll run. -- I am not familiar with OpenVX. some implementations (it's a standard) might be small enough to fit. this lists some cortex M4 controllers: https://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products/openvx RP2040 is M0+, which doesn't even have an FPU

Comment: I need a very cheep microcontroller which can run OpenCV and make simple object detection on board (I need a lot of it)? Is there available something appropriate cheaper that Raspberry/Orange Pi?

Comment: Did you find anything suitable? Also looking for the same